# flask_admin - How can we filter selectable values in a form drop down?

Tags: flask-admin

I have a form with a select box. How can i put a filter so that only specific objects are shown?

```
class XYZ(ModelView):
  column_list = ['id', 'selection']
```

I want to put a filter so that while creating/updating only those `selection` objects are shown that satisfy a particular predicate.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class XYZ(ModelView):
  column_list = ['id', 'selection']
  column_filters = ['selection']
```

Or for possibly more custom SQL from thedocs. http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import BaseSQLAFilter

class FilterLastNameBrown(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        if value == '1':
            return query.filter(self.column == "Brown")
        else:
            return query.filter(self.column != "Brown")

    def operation(self):
        return 'is Brown'

class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_filters = [
        FilterLastNameBrown(
            User.last_name, 'Last Name', options=(('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No'))
        )
    ]
```